# validation dependency error java spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, dependencies

My pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

but every time I run the project (as of today, it worked 2 days ago), I get:

```
2023-05-14 12:53:53,691 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Action:

Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone got any idea why?
Already did `mvn clean install`, no luck there.